# How is the regular expression [1-57-9] interpreted?

Tags: java, regex, expression

This is in Java: `[1-57-9]`

I came across this regular expression today, and I am trying to find out what it means exactly. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: That's not *3* numbers. They are actually **4** numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's allowing the digits 1-5 and 7-9. So it's equivalent to `[12345789]`.

See the docs for [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for the details of regular expressions in Java, in particular the examples under "Character classes":

> - `[abc]` - `a`, `b`, or `c` (simple class)
> - `[^abc]` - Any character except `a`, `b`, or `c` (negation)
> - `[a-zA-Z]` - `a` through `z` or `A` through `Z`, inclusive (range)
> - `[a-d[m-p]]` - `a` through `d`, or `m` through `p`: `[a-dm-p]` (union)
> - `[a-z&&[def]]` - `d`, `e`, or `f` (intersection)
> - `[a-z&&[^bc]]` - `a` through `z`, except for `b` and `c`: `[ad-z]` (subtraction)
> - `[a-z&&[^m-p]]` - `a` through `z`, and not `m` through `p`: `[a-lq-z]` (subtraction)

See also the [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info) web site, and its [section on character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Comment: This link: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html may also be helpful.

Comment: @RohitJain: Thanks, will include it.

Comment: +1 for showing the intersection and subtraction. Those are lesser known and very rarely used feature of character class.

Comment: @RohitJain: They're just the examples from the documentation :)

Answer (score 2):

Read `[1-57-9]` as "1 to 5 or 7 to 9"

It matches a digit in 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9.

Answer (score 2):

It's simply a [character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) that specifys that you can match a single digit in the range: 1 to 5 and 7 to 9.

Answer (score 0):

It means one of the following characters:
    1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9